# test.each`` table syntax to get method return value?

Tags: jestjs

To make for more readable test titles, I want to access methods in the title. I recognize the syntax for properties, but I don't know if what I want to achieve is possible.

```
test.each`
      dialogStack | expectedHandler
      ${[d1, d2, d3]} | ${handle1}
      ${[d2, d3, d1]} | ${handle1}
      ${[d3, d1, d2]} | ${handle1}
      ${[d3, d1, d2, d4]} | ${handle4}
      `( '$expectedHandler.getMockName() should handle the event in $dialogStack',
```

this is a portion of my code, I know that $expectedHandler.property is a valid syntax but can I get the return value of a method?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you don't have access to `expectedHandler`'s methods in the description of a `test.each`, the description converts the function to a string value.